# Azure DevOps pipeline repository trigger doesn't fire

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

### Context

I'm creating a CI/CD configuration for an application having this repository configuration (each repository in the same Organization and Project):

- Frontend repository (**r1**)
- API Service repository (**r2**)
- Infrastructure As Code repo (**r3**)

Within the repository **r3** there are the solution's Azure DevOps Pipelines, each one of them has been configured for *Manual & Scheduled trigger on **develop** branch*:

1. Frontend CI Pipeline **p1**
2. Backend CI Pipeline **p2**
3. Deployment Pipeline **p3**

The behavior I want is

1. Git commit on **r1** repo
2. Pipeline **p1** on repo **r3** triggered (this will create artifacts, apply a tag and notify)
3. Pipeline **p3** triggered by p1 completion (this will deploy the artifacts)

Pipeline **p1** looks like the following

```yaml
trigger: none

resources:
  containers:
    - container: running-image
      image: ubuntu:latest
      options: "-v /usr/bin/sudo:/usr/bin/sudo -v /usr/lib/sudo/libsudo_util.so.0:/usr/lib/sudo/libsudo_util.so.0 -v /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so:/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so -v /etc/sudoers:/etc/sudoers"
  repositories:
    - repository: frontend
      name: r1
      type: git
      ref: develop
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - develop
          exclude:
            - main

name: $(SourceBranchName)_$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r) - Frontend App [CI]

variables:
  - name: imageName
    value: fronted-app
  - name: containerRegistryConnection
    value: apps-registry-connection

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build and push
    jobs:
      - job: JobBuild
        displayName: Build job
        container: running-image
        steps:
          - checkout: frontend
            displayName: Checkout Frontend repository
            path: fe
            persistCredentials: true

...
```

Pipeline **p3** looks like the following

```yaml
name: $(SourceBranchName)_$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r) - App [CD]
trigger: none

resources:
  containers:
    - container: running-image
      image: ubuntu:latest
      options: "-v /usr/bin/sudo:/usr/bin/sudo -v /usr/lib/sudo/libsudo_util.so.0:/usr/lib/sudo/libsudo_util.so.0 -v /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so:/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so -v /etc/sudoers:/etc/sudoers"
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: app-fe-delivery
      source: "p1"
      trigger:
        stages:
          - Build
        branches:
          include:
            - develop


pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
stages:
  - stage: Delivery
    jobs:
      - job: JobDevelopment
        steps:
          - template: ../templates/template-setup.yaml # Template reference
            parameters:
              serviceDisplayName: ${{ variables.serviceDisplayName }}
              serviceName: ${{ variables.serviceName }}
...
```

### Issue

Even if followed step by step all the rules exposed in the official documentation:

- Pipeline **p1** is never triggered by any commit on **develop** branch in **r1** repository
- Even if manually run Pipeline **p1**, Pipeline **p3** is never triggered

### Remarks

- As stated in the [pipelines YAML reference](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/pipeline-triggers.md#schema-1), Triggers are enabled by default
- in the same documentation, if no **branch include filter** is expressed, the trigger will happen on all branches
- As stated in the [triggers for Checkout Multiple repositories in pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers) triggers happens only for repos in Azure DevOps repositories
- is it possible to disable pipeline CI triggers (`trigger: none`) and have resource's repositories triggers happening
- Build agent user has been authorized to access and queue new builds

Answer (score 0):

Couple possible solutions.

First off believe your issue is with:

```
trigger: none
```

This means the pipeline will only work manually. In the documentation you referenced :

> Triggers are enabled by default on all the resources. However, you can choose to override/disable triggers for each resource.

[The way this is configured all push triggers are disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#push-trigger).

One possible way to achieve what you are attempting I believe is to remove the `trigger:none` from **p1** and **p3**

If I read your question correctly you are trying to do a CI/CD build deployment on the repository. If so, may I suggest if the scenario is appropriate (i.e. a Build will always trigger a deployment) then combine these pipelines into one and put an `if` statement around the deployment stage similar to:

```
  - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')}}:
```

Also, if deploying to multiple environments this can be followed up with a loop indented in one line:

```
  - ${{ each environmentNames in parameters.environmentNames }}:
```

I noticed you are already using template so this would be just moving the template call up from the job to the stage and have it act as a wrapper.  Feel free to provide feedback.  If this answer isn't appropriate, I can update it accordingly.

Comment: Anyway, just to add a bit of context more, what I have is a repository with pipelines that should be triggered by two external repositories, frontend, and backend.
The point about the `trigger: none` is correct if you want to trigger the self repository (the one where pipelines lives) a pipeline with CI triggers, and this must be configured in the trigger section.
The point is slightly different if you want to be triggered by another repo (not the self).

Comment: To accomplish that you have to do 2 things, disable the self CI trigger and enable the trigger for the external repo using the resources/repositories/repository/trigger... and you can read about that here about [multirepo checkout triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers).
About the rest, I too I was thinking of merging CI/CD into one using Stages and some gates using variables. 
Thanks a lot again for your response